# why we use infopath in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

Can anyone explain why we use infopath in sharepoint?

Answer (score 3):

Infopath is mainly used as a "code free" approach to creating a form for collecting user data.

One of the main benefits when integrated with SharePoint is the ability to use the InfoPath form in conjunction with a [workflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386211.aspx), which can automate many different business processes.

Answer (score 1):

1. Can be created and published by an Information Worker without or very little support from developers.
2. You can arrive at a screen for Data entry in matter of no time.
3. Tight integration between SharePoint & Infopath.